# Substitute row in Numpy if a condition is met - Variation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

I am still figuring out Numpy syntax! I have something that works but there must be a more concise way to perform this task.  In the example below, I replace selected rows of an array with new entries, where the condition is just on one element.

```
import numpy as np
big_array = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 2)) # multi-dimension array
print(big_array)
bad_values = np.less_equal(big_array[:,0], 4)  # condition value in one dimension
bad_rows = np.nonzero(bad_values)[0]           # indexes to change, e.g. rows
print(f'these are the rows to replace {bad_rows}')
new_rows = np.random.randint(10, size=((bad_rows.size),2))+10  # smaller multi-dim array
np.put(big_array[:,0],bad_rows,y[:,0])   # should be a single line to combine this
np.put(big_array[:,1],bad_rows,y[:,1])   # with this?
print(big_array)
```

sample output that I want might look like

```
[[2 4]
 [5 9]
 [6 6]
 [6 7]
 [0 6]]
 these are the rows to replace [0 4]
 [[16 17]
 [ 5  9]
 [ 6  6]
 [ 6  7]
 [18 17]]
```

I don't know how to format `put` for arguments with different dimensions.  This seems like it should be a one-liner. (If I try `where` I get length issues broadcasting.)  What am I missing?

Comment: `big_array[bad_values] = np.random.randint(10, size=(np.count_nonzero(bad_values),2))+10`, should work, you only need *bad_values*

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Wow, I overthought it.  I was looking through all the cool Numpy commands, and I did not need any of them!  Straight addressing works.  My actual code calls a more complicated function, but in the end, this approach seems to work fine.

Comment: You might also be interested in [`put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) more generally.

Comment: I tried `put_along_axis` earlier but I got mismatch problems.  Errors like `indices` and `arr` must have the same number of dimensions.  Not sure when to use this.